# Changing default file permission on redis dump

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, redis

I have a cron job, which is running under a user called 'deployer' with limited access. The cron job is performing a backup of my redis database resulting in a dum /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb.

Now the cron job now tries to perform a `/bin/gzip -c /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb > /home/deployer/Backup/.tmp/redis_backup/databases/Redis/dump.rdb.gz` before shipping it off to S3. The problem is, that the permissions on /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb is -rw-rw----, so I get the following error:

```
gzip: /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb: Permission denied
```

So my question is, I'm not interested in giving my deployer user wider permissions, so I would like that dump, that is being created every time the cron job is run, to have other permissions.

How can I accomplish that the simplest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Redis dump file is created with a standard fopen('...',"w") call. So the access rights are actually inherited from the current [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).

Try to alter the umask in the script or the shell used to launch the Redis server, before launching the Redis server itself, by using the umask command:

```
$ umask 022
```

This command will change the mask so that new files will be created with 644 access rights (666 being the default access rights).

Comment: Worked like a charm, I changed it in the init.d script for redid-server in start command :-)