# How to set Redis's dump.rdb file permissions?

Tags: redis, file-permissions

I want to write a script that dumps my database and makes a backup of if. However I've faced a problem. I need to `SAVE` database and after that I need to copy a file to another location. The thing is, after I run a `SAVE` command with redis-cli, the file permissions are overwritten and set to `-rw-rw----`.

How to tell Redis to save the `dump.rdb` with another permissions?

I've found this answer: [Changing default file permission on redis dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364713/changing-default-file-permission-on-redis-dump), it describes the same problem I'm facing, however setting `umask` didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, thanks to the guys at Redis repository at Github.

Here's how I solved it:

`sudo systemctl edit redis-server.service`

In the editor, type;

`[Service]
UMask=0002`

And then run `systemctl reenable redis-server.service` and `systemctl restart redis-server`.